# How to download eclipselink jar file from internet in Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, centos, eclipselink

Hello I want to download jar file from this link in linux. http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/rt/eclipselink/releases/2.5.2/eclipselink-plugins-2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.zip&mirror_id=1063

I used wget command with no success. It only downloads web page not jar. 
My command is:

`wget 'http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/rt/eclipselink/releases/2.5.2/eclipselink-plugins-2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.zip&mirror_id=1063'`

Comment: Show your `wget` command. Did you quote your URL (since `?` is interpreted by the shell)? And you might need to have some cookie...

Comment: command: wget 'http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/rt/eclipselink/releases/2.5.2/eclipselink-plugins-2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.zip&mirror_id=1063' I didn't use any cookie

Comment: you should edit the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the "click here" link location:

```
wget 'ftp://ftp.stu.edu.tw/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/releases/2.5.2/eclipselink-plugins-2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.zip'
```